# Unexpected output of 'od'

Tags: linux, binary, octal

I don't understand the output from the 'od' program.

Suppose I write the content "abc" in a test file:

```
echo "abc" > test.txt
```

then the characters a (01100001), b (01100010) and c (01100011) get converted to binary via an ASCII table and saved in the file.
So I would expect the file would contain the following bits

```
011000010110001001100011
```

If I convert the file with 'xxd', the result is the following:

```
$ cat test.txt | xxd -b
00000000: 01100001 01100010 01100011 00001010                    abc.
```

*(The last 8 bits (.) already confuses me but I think it's because the ouput of 'cat')*

**Now:** If I try to convert the file with 'od', the following picture emerges

```
$ od test.txt
0000000 061141 005143
0000004
```

I have my problems here. I can't understand how od come up with these numbers.
As far as I understand, od takes a byte (e.g. the first -> 01100001 -> 'a') and converts this number into the octal number system. But this should result in '141'.

Can someone explain this issue to me?

Comment: That last byte in test.txt is a newline.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `od` get from `ab` to `061141`

ab => 0x6162 => 0x6261 (swap bytes) = 25185 (deciaml) = 061141 (octal)